# Nodejs, Include Static Codegen Protobuf/gRPC files from outside of project

Tags: node.js, static, protocol-buffers, external, grpc

Good day,

I am using protoc to generate pb files for nodejs. This step works fine. The proto files, and the code generated from them, are kept in a central location since different services will be using them (server and clients). If I copy these files into my project and use them, everything works fine. If I try requiring the files from the central location (which is outside of my project) I get an error

> Error: Cannot find module 'google-protobuf'

The core of the question is, how do I require a file from outside of my project, that in turn requires a module from my project? Can this be done? I would have imagined that once the file was requires through relative pathing, it would become a part of the project, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Please help.